# Interactive service Logged in as user

Tags: service, rake, cruisecontrol.net, watin, interactive

So we are trying to setup a Continuous Integration server at my company. What we need to do is svn update the working copy on the server, then build it, start the site using IIS express and then run Watin/Specflow tests on it. I'm using rake inside of CCNet to automate all of this. We are running CCNet as a service and logging in as a build agent because svn uses our domain login credentials in order to authenticate. I've been unable to call the command line "svn update --username user --password pass" because of this. Yet Watin needs to be run in an interactive mode, and the service won't let me . I'm able to get it to work if we manually log on to the server and run ccnet as command line. Unfortunately the Build Agent also logs out of that user account, closing any command lines with it (I don't know why they need it to do this but they do). So is it possible to run a service in interactive mode if its signed in as a user?

Comment: So I'm currently trying to use powershell to change the login credentials of the process running. No dice so far.

Comment: I decided to try and run ccnet.exe inside of a powershell script which itself was being launched by ccservice. But when the script puts in the credentials, it get's an access denied

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to two servers you can build (can also work from computer to server)

- Automated remote desktop - in windows form
- see this post http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET

from one server to log into the server you need to run the Watin tests on and in the scheduled task, have the tests to come on after the log in has happened. This then gives the impression that the service is interacting with the desktop.

If you need any more information let me know